# Can anyone suggest a idea on how do I pass the value from my useState (toDoData1 and toDoData2) to MapRegion (latitude and longitude)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

My code

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions, Button } from 'react-native'
import React , {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {ref, onValue} from 'firebase/database'
import {db} from '../firebase'
import MapView, {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';
import * as Loc from 'expo-location';

const Location = ({route}) => {
  const paramKey = route.params.paramKey1
  console.log(paramKey)
  var ke, latit, longit;
  const [todoDatak, setToDoDatak] = useState([])
  
  const [todoDatal, setToDoDatal] = useState([])
  const [todoData2, setToDoData2] = useState([])

  const [mapRegion, setMapRegion] = useState({
    latitude: toDoData1,
    longitude: toDoData2,
    latitudeDelta: 0.9,
    longitudeDelta:0.9,
  })
  
  const [mapRegionNow, setMapRegionNow] = useState({
    latitude: 1.3483,
    longitude: 103.6831,
    latitudeDelta: 0.9,
    longitudeDelta:0.9,
  })
  
  useEffect (() => {
    const starCountRef = ref(db, "food/" + paramKey);
    onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) =>{
 
      latit = snapshot.val().Latitude
      console.log("Value from Firebase: " + latit)
      longit = snapshot.val().Longitude
      console.log("Value from Firebase: " + longit);
      
      ke = snapshot.key;
      setToDoDatak(ke)
      
      setToDoDatal(latit)
      setToDoData2(longit)
     
      });
      userLocation();
    }, [])
    console.log('Latitude = ' + todoDatal)
    console.log('Longitude = ' + todoData2)
```

I cant seem to set the **latitude** and **longitude** from **toDoData1** and **toDoData2**.

My console logs to ensure correct value is extracted and stored:

[image]

I tried changing

```
const [todoDatal, setToDoDatal] = useState([])
const [todoData2, setToDoData2] = useState([])
```

to

```
const [todoDatal, setToDoDatal] = useState()
const [todoData2, setToDoData2] = useState()
```

The change above was I was having the error of `Cannot pass ReadableNativeArray for latitude`

But after the change, it still didnt work for me. I get the error shown in my app:

[image]

Can anyone help me on this? Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issued solved: Answer by @Wodin

With the change stated in the question and a change under MapView

```
{toDoData1 && toDoData2 && <Marker coordinate={{ toDoData1, toDoData2 }} title={"my marker"}/>}
```